# Permission denied to access node.cfg

Tags: 14.04

I install bro on ubuntu14, in path= `/usr/local/bro`

When I type `root@ubuntu:~# /usr/local/bro/logs/current/reporter.log`

```
error :
bash: /usr/local/bro/logs/current/reporter.log: Permission denied
```

What? I use `su` and `sudo -i` and `sudo su` to become root

Comment: What kind of action u r performing exactly...use sudo prefix and type password when asked

Comment: i type sudo -i and password and i became root, but i type su and password :su: Authentication failure

Comment: So what do u want to do exactly

Comment: and i type sudo su without password :root@ubuntu:/home/eng-it#

Comment: U dont have to type password again and again once typed in the same session.so it didn't ask again for password

Comment: what can not access to reporter.cfg and node.cfg ....?

Comment: There is reportor.log file....type sudo gedit /usr....../reportor.log

Comment: Since this solved your problem.. please tick √ below downvote and upvote

Comment: Don't add solved to the question title, accept the answer that worked with the checkmark below.

Answer (score 2):

Type

```
 sudo gedit /usr..../report.log
```

You need to perform a action (here `gedit`) with superuser permissions. Typing `sudo /usr...` is not a action.